# Simple Python Program - unsure with Range and loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, range

Here is the psuedo code I was supposed to create in python:

```
PlayerOneScore ← 0
PlayerTwoScore ← 0
OUTPUT "How many games?"
INPUT NoOfGamesInMatch
FOR NoOfGamesPlayed ← 1 TO NoOfGamesInMatch Do
    OUTPUT "Did Player One win the game (enter Y or N)?"
    INPUT PlayerOneWinsGame
    IF PlayerOneWinsGame = 'Y'
        THEN PlayerOneScore ← PlayerOneScore + 1
        ELSE PlayerTwoScore ← PlayerTwoScore + 1
    ENDIF
ENDFOR
OUTPUT PlayerOneScore
OUTPUT PlayerTwoScore
```

Here is what I created in python and its not working and I don't understand why?

```
PlayerOneScore = 0
PlayerTwoSCore = 0
NoOfGamesInMatch = input("How Many games?")
for NoOfGamesPlayed != NoOfGamesInMatch:  
    PlayerOneWinsGame = input(" Did Player on win the game(Enter y or N?)")
    if PlayerOneWinsGame == "Y":
        PlayerOneScore = PlayerOneScore + 1
    else:
        PlayerTwoScore = PlayerTwoScore = 1
print("Player one Score is" + str(PlayerOneScore))
print("Player Two Score is" + str(PlayerTwoScore))
```

I tried the `in range` part, and I got this error when I input one when the program input how many games.

```
    for NoOfGamesPlayed in range(NoOfGamesInMatch):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: How is the code not working? What input did you give it, what happened and what did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: ```for NoOfGamesPlayed != NoOfGamesInMatch``` this have no sense.

Comment: `for NoOfGamesPlayed != NoOfGamesInMatch` is not valid Python code. You tagged this with `while-loop`, perhaps you meant to use `while` there? If so, how do you increment your loop counter?

Comment: Just a tip, in Python we name variable `like_this`, for example `PlayerOneScore` should be `player_one_score`. We use Pascal Case for classes which is what you are doing. It could be confusing to other people reading your code.

Comment: @IanAuld: the same goes for you. Style guides are not helpful at this juncture.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I tried the in range part, and i got this error when i input one when the program input how many games."for NoOfGamesPlayed in range(NoOfGamesInMatch):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Comment: @Danielb7: See, now we are getting somewhere. :-) Add that to your question, and I won't forget about such things.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters thanks i will

Comment: @Danielb7: in future, *include* such details. It tells us what you already tried, and what went wrong with that.

Comment: Typo at `PlayerTwoScore = PlayerTwoScore = 1`, not what is causing your problem though. I believe you want to use `while` instead of `for`, since `for` in Python has a special usage and is supposed to be used with arrays. Just remember you will have to increment `NoOfGamesPlayed` yourself if you use `while`, it won't do it automatically.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line

```
for NoOfGamesPlayed != NoOfGamesInMatch:
```

is not valid Python. If you wanted to use looping here, `for` is helpful but you need to add a `range()` function:

```
for NoOfGamesPlayed in range(int(NoOfGamesInMatch)):
```

See the [Python tutorial on the `for` construct](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements). Since the `input()` function returns a *string*, you need to convert it to an integer first, using the [`int()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

Your code otherwise pretty much matches the pseudo-code otherwise, apart from using a lowercase `y` in your `input()` line; you may want to correct that as you only test for *uppercase* `Y` in the result:

```
PlayerOneWinsGame = input("Did Player One win the game (enter Y or N?)")
```

You also made a small typo in your `PlayerTwoScore` update; replace the second `=` with `+`:

```
PlayerTwoScore = PlayerTwoScore + 1
```

Putting that together would make:

```
PlayerOneScore = 0
PlayerTwoSCore = 0
NoOfGamesInMatch = input("How Many games?")
for NoOfGamesPlayed in range(int(NoOfGamesInMatch)):
    PlayerOneWinsGame = input("Did Player One win the game (enter Y or N?)")
    if PlayerOneWinsGame == "Y":
        PlayerOneScore = PlayerOneScore + 1
    else:
        PlayerTwoScore = PlayerTwoScore + 1
print("Player one Score is" + str(PlayerOneScore))
print("Player Two Score is" + str(PlayerTwoScore))
```

Comment: Thanks this worked a charm. You made a Typo "PlayerTwoSCore", should be "PlayerTwoScore". thanks for the advice

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to change entities names according to PEP-0008?

Comment: @IgorPomaranskiy: that's not actually going to be helpful here.  PEP 8 tells you that you need to stick to the *existing conventions*; here that means camel-case variables. This is a UK exam question (from June 2010, this student is practicing, not cheating) and that exam uses camel-casing throughout and supports multiple languages, not just Python.

Comment: @IgorPomaranskiy: PEP-8 is [low hanging fruit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf-BqAjZb8M); focusing on that is not actually going to help the question asker learn about the actual problems.

Comment: @MartijnPieters look, the newbie come for help to community of cool, mature developers. He writes a piece of code which violates a lot of rules, which are supposed to be followed by community. And here we are to the rescue, explaining to him about loops and some other basic things. But keeping all bad approaches untouched and undiscussed. Then he keeps writing bad code, probably until his first real-job interviews. Did we help him, staying focused on his 'actual problems'?

Comment: @IgorPomaranskiy: style guides are **minor issues**. Style issues can easily be fixed. Understanding how code works is much harder to fix. I do recommend you watch Raymond's talk about fixing code *properly* and not just to get fixated on a style guide.

Answer (score 1):

In every language, `for` loops are more commonly used to iterate over a range of value as in

```
for record in records
for file in files
for i in range(0, 10)
for prime_number in [11, 13, 19]
```

On the other hand, `while` loops are used to perform blocks of code **while** a given condition evaluates to true

```
while i_am_hunger: eat()
while list_is_empty
while list_is_not_empty
```

And so on.

It seems to me that your case fits more in a `while` loop. Something like:

```
while NoOfGamesPlayed != NoOfGamesInMatch:  *do something*
```

Last note:
Python has some style guides that are intended to keep your code cleaner. While style is sometimes a personal choice, it would be nice if you take some time to read them. For instance, in your case, your variable names should be divided by underscore as in `no_of_games_played`. Checkout more here:

[Google Style Guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html)

[PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008)

Comment: For what it's worth, the [mark scheme (page 27)](https://www.school-portal.co.uk/GroupDownloadFile.asp?GroupID=1211959&ResourceId=4551018) for this exam expects the variables to be using the original camel casing

Comment: Good to know! Well, I did not know this question was for a test. OP, adhere to the given naming convention in this case

Answer (score -1):

If I've guessed your intentions, the code should look like this:

```
player_one_score = 0
player_two_score = 0

games_in_match = input("How Many games?")

for i in range(games_in_match):  
    player_one_wins = input(" Did Player One win the game(Enter Y or N?)")
    if player_one_wins.upper() == "Y":
        player_one_score += 1
    else:
        player_two_score += 1

print("Player One Score is {}".format(player_one_score))
print("Player Two Score is {}".format(player_two_score))
```

Comment: The title of the question suggests that they should be using `for` and `range`, not `while`. Without an explanation, this isn't very helpful for the OP; don't just give them code. Why does this work? Where did they go wrong?

Comment: Updated the code. I believe that working code is much better (and quick) tutorial point, than dealing with contains tons of errors. OP can compare the versions and find out what has changed.

Comment: Now imagine the teacher reading this and asking the student about how they got this lovely code, and could they explain how it works? What does the `format()` call do? Where did they read about the augmented assignment syntax? And the student would not be able to tell them any of that.

Comment: Your code gives them a fish, while they were really asking about how to fish.

Comment: I suppose that students are smart enough to google for unknown code entities. Besides that, they can just to play with the _working_ code and try to apply different approaches. :)